# permissions on a new folder in php

Tags: php, chmod

My code looks like this:

```
do
{
    $rand = rand(1,10000000); 
    $name_of_file_clear = $rand ;
    $name_of_file = $rand . '.JPG' ;
    $name_of_file_t = $rand . '_t.JPG' ; // for thubnsdffafasf
    $this_directory_path = str_replace(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    $images_directory_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $this_directory_path . 'img/' . $name_of_file_clear . '/';
    $whole_path = $images_directory_path.$name_of_file;
} while (file_exists($whole_path));

mkdir($images_directory_path, 777);
chmod($images_directory_path, 777);
move_uploaded_file($temp_file_name, $whole_path);
```

The problem is, when I try uploading file, the file is not uploaded. I think the problem is something with the permissions. Help me please, I am new to php.

Comment: If you enable `error_reporting` & `display_errors`, PHP will tell you whether it's a permission problem...

Comment: Instead of _thinking_ the problem is with permissions, PHP will _tell you_ which path it tries to write to, and why it can't write there. So yes, that would help you. If you develop without showing the errors PHP is trying to show you so helpfully, not only will you just handicap yourself, you may even find others unwilling to help unless you show them your actual errors.

Comment: i found this site http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/1718
i didnt understand how to make it to show the errors? where should i put it?

Comment: That snippet can go at the very start of your code. However, it can't catch parse errors, so even better (when using apache & .htaccess enabled) is putting in your `.htaccess` the following 2 lines: `php_value error_reporting 32767` and `php_flag display_errors on`.

Comment: ok, i'll try this, i dont really know what apache and htaccess are, but i'll look in the web

Answer (score 5):

You're specifying them in decimal. Try specifying them in octal instead.

```
mkdir($images_directory_path, 0777);
```